# Override django form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been research a lot about this, but don't get any answer accurate. Here's the deal: I want to override where forms.Field is used from my own, that is, where all classes that inherit from forms.Field, inherit from my own. Why? I like to add some properties that i'll use in every single field.

Anyone?

Comment: Please be more specific!
1> What do you want override in forms.Field, i'm thinking styling?
2> What properties?, changing field type?, id?

Comment: I want to add properties related to column and row for make a general template, and mount the grid based on that properties.

Comment: Do you want to **overwrite** the `forms.Field` so yours is used instead of the Django one, or you want to **override** it so yours is used every time you want to use a Django form?

Comment: Yes,  overwrite. Sorry for the words. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which i used, please keep in mind that this field is purely for text-fields, for passwords you have to manually override form value fields.

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="custom_class_here ">
{% if field.errors%}
    <div class="custom_class_here">
        {{ field.errors }}
    </div>
{% endif %} 
{% if field.help_text %}
     <p class="custom_class_here">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
{% endif %}
     <input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" name="{{ field.html_name }}" id="{{field.id_for_label}}" class="custom_class_here" placeholder="{{field.label}}" value= "{{field.value|default_if_none:''}}">
    </div>            
{% endfor %}
```

Also for checkbox, select, passwords dropdowns etc you have to write separate if conditions and and alter fields accordingly.

I referred Vitor's [site](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html)

Comment: No man, this i already make, i want to override forms.Field, not to do with templates, please read the question, thanks.

Comment: I'm am not understanding your exact requirements, you said you wanted to add properties to your form template?

Comment: No, I want to add properties to edit class Field on django.forms and upload to server in my own virtual env, understood?